# How I can make my API public?

Tags: php, laravel

I am new in PHP
 and i  have this API

> http://localhost/category/read.php

and here is the required headers for this API :

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
```

I want to make it public to use it with get and post method

how can i do this ??

Comment: What do you mean by public?

Comment: @quinz everyone  can read the content of  this api

Comment: @B001 exactly ..

Comment: @Dina buy a domain and host it if you want make it public

Answer (score 0):

Your web project is currently hosted locally which means it **only exists on your home computer.**

If you want other people to use it you will need to get both hosting and a domain to host it on.

For Domains I would personally recommend:

[Google Domains](https://domains.google/)

[NameCheap](https://www.namecheap.com/)

For Hosting I would personally recommend:

[DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/)

*There are tons of providers out there, these are just my preferences.*

To get your Laravel Project on this server you can use Laravel's Paid service:

[Laravel Forge](http://forge.laravel.com)

or follow one of many tutorials like so:

[Tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-laravel-application-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 0):

On api.php

Move your routes outside the route::group